# Give the exact solution of the equation $e^x - \dfrac{1}{x} = m$, where $m$ is a real number

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

Problem: Give the exact solution of the equation
$$e^x - \dfrac{1}{x} = m.$$

By taking the derivative of the function $f(x) = e^x-\dfrac{1}{x}$, we have $f$ is an increasing function and also takes the value over the real numbers. But, I get difficulty when solving exactly this equation. I am very much appreciated it if anyone can give me some hints.

Comment: I suppose you have already come to this point, but just in case you haven't, perhaps you know how to simplify this $x = W(mx+1)$. If it can be simplified, then the question is solved. Here $W(x) := xe^x$, more popularly known as the product log function

Comment: @Macavity You are... absolutely right. Utter brain blip.

Comment: @Hersh I think you meant $x=W(x)e^{W(x)}$ or $W(xe^x)=x$.